# Distribution of a function of exponential and uniform random variables?

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution

Consider the following independent random variables:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
A &\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_1), \\[6pt]
C &\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_2), \\[6pt]
B &\sim \text{U}(0,1), \\[6pt]
D &\sim \text{U}(0,1). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Define the random variable:

$$M \equiv \frac{(A+BC)^2}{AC(B-1)^2 + CD + A + C}.$$

How do I find the distribution of this random variable?

Comment: Could you explain where $M$ comes from?  It is so strange (a non-homogeneous rational function of degree four) that one wonders whether it might be an attempt to solve a problem in an unusual way and that (therefore) a better way might be available.  It is highly unlikely you will obtain any simple closed form for the distribution of $M.$

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulate it (this is python)

```
import numpy as np 
lambda1 = 1.0
N = 1000000
A = np.random.exponential(scale=lambda1,size=N)
B = np.random.uniform(size=N)
C = np.random.exponential(scale=lambda1,size=N)
D = np.random.uniform(size=N)
M = (A+B*C)**2/(A*C*(B-1)**2 + C*D + A + C) # N realizations of the random variable 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
_ = plt.hist(M, bins=5000, density=True) # plot
```

Here it is. You could regress something to it for practical purposes. 
The other way would be to use your rules for combinations of random variables and work really hard. I don't know what that would become

[image]

Comment: I need a mathematical expression for the pdf(M).